# Github Pages only show index.html contents when navigating to markdown link

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I am setting up a Github Pages site and the index.html, css, etc are all working fine.

When I create a .md file in _posts using the syntax YYYY-MM-DD-title-of-post.md, I can navigate to username.github.io/YYYY/MM/DD/title-of-post and not get a 404, but it only shows the contents of my index.html file.

Here's the link to the gh-p: https://jacobkreider.github.io

And a sample of the issue: https://jacobkreider.github.io/2018/06/12/try-again

Why would this happen? Is there a redirect or something in there I don't know about? I am publishing via the web interface, but get the same issue from Desktop, as well as the command line.

I see the same thing when I try and load the index file from my /blog/ folder (to try and see a list of published posts).

I'm stuck- any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: It appears it is just showing my default layout under the _layouts folder. Changes to index.html or additional file posts aren't shown anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the repo for your site. You have the same block of code `<div class="blurb"> ... </div>` in `/index.html` and in `/_layouts/default.html`. You only need this code in `/index.html`.

In `/_layouts/default.html`, replace that `div` with `{{ content }}` so that it looks like

```
...
</nav>
<div class="container">
    {{ content }}
</div><!-- /.container -->
<footer>
...
```

Since you specified `layout: default` in the front matter in `/index.html`, Jekyll uses the `/_layouts/default.html`, stores the actual content of `/index.html` in the `content` variable, and inserts all that stuff into the layout using `{{ content }}`. Since you're missing `{{ content }}`, that's why none of your changes to posts or `/index.html` are showing up.

Comment: It seems like you're following the tutorial from [http://jmcglone.com/guides/github-pages/](http://jmcglone.com/guides/github-pages/) and you forgot to do step 9.

Answer (score 0):

Your **default** layout doesn't output `{{ content }}`. Edit this file to read :

```
...
<div class="container">
  {{ content }}
</div>
...
```